# SharePoint Search Center issue

Tags: 2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 with collaboration portal template on Windows Server 2008. The default search address for a site is pointed to /SearchCenter/Pages/Results.aspx. Any ideas how to change the address to some other address?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Site Settings and under Site Collection Administration there is a Search Settings link. You can change the address there.

Comment: Cool, question answered!